# Facing this error in experience editor

Tags: jss, experience-editor

`jss start:connected` command is also not working,

I used following comands
`jss setup`
`jss deploy config`
`jss deploy app -c -d`

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\adac11sc.dev.local",
    "apiKey": "{0CE3552A-3647-405E-9BCF-9A4A86DA90D8}",
    "deploySecret": "ruxi40eig744rht68tz5cvypn2m6pfdc16xy01htuf",
    "deployUrl": "http://sitecore-jss-app.dev.local/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "http://sitecore-jss-app.dev.local"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace your screenshots with error text for SEO reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There might be serveral possibilites and hope the following can helps:

1. Check your configuration, to ensure your `sitecore.apiKey` and `sitecore.layoutServiceHost` config values set correctly and match.
2. Verify you can get JSON response from accessing the URL like `http://[your instance domain]/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={API_KEY}`
3. Ensure your content are all `published` successfully. And make sure bundle and manifest files have been generated.
4. Check the `JSS app's logs` for more details .